# How to count columns in a range with nonzero values?

Tags: r, sum, mean, countif

I am essentially trying to replicate the COUNTIF function from excel. I have a data frame called `filtered.data` like so:

```
  Experiment_ID t_20_n_6 t_20_n_5 t_20_n_4 t_20_n_3 t_20_n_2 t_20_n_1
1  SG100520_social_01        0        0        0        0        2        1
2  K8012921_social_03        0        0        0        0        0        1
3  K8020521_social_01        0        0        0        1        1        1
4  K8020521_social_02        0        0        1        0        0        1
5  K8020521_social_03        0        0        0        0        2        3
6  K8020521_social_04        0        0        0        1        1        2
7  K8020521_social_05        0        0        0        1        1        3
8  K8021221_social_01        1        0        0        0        0        1
9  K8021221_social_03        0        0        0        0        0        2
10 K8021221_social_04        0        0        0        2        0        1
```

And I need to calculate a sort of average for t_20_n_6:t_20_n_1. I have the totaling part down by using `x <- filtered.data %>% mutate(t_20_mean = ( (6*t_20_n_6)+(5*t_20_n_5)+(4*t_20_n_4)+(3*t_20_n_3)+(2*t_20_n_2)+(1*t_20_n_1) )\ ~~~~)`

but I need to replace the ~~~~ with a count of the number of nonzero columns from t_20_n_6:t_20_n_1.

I have tried `sum(x$t_10_n_6 != 0 | x$t_20_n_5 != 0 | x$t_20_n_4 != 0 | x$t_20_n_3 != 0 | x$t_20_n_2 !=0 | x$t_20_n_1 != 0 )` but the numbers don't make sense.

The results should be:

```
        Experiment_ID t_20_n_6 t_20_n_5 t_20_n_4 t_20_n_3 t_20_n_2 t_20_n_1 t_20_mean
1  SG100520_social_01        0        0        0        0        2        1         2.5
2  K8012921_social_03        0        0        0        0        0        1         1
3  K8020521_social_01        0        0        0        1        1        1         2
4  K8020521_social_02        0        0        1        0        0        1         2.5
5  K8020521_social_03        0        0        0        0        2        3         3.5
6  K8020521_social_04        0        0        0        1        1        2         2.33
7  K8020521_social_05        0        0        0        1        1        3         2.67
8  K8021221_social_01        1        0        0        0        0        1         3.5
9  K8021221_social_03        0        0        0        0        0        2         2
10 K8021221_social_04        0        0        0        2        0        1         3.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in using the number (1 through 6) embedded in the column names for weighting, you could also try this approach.

Use `pivot_longer` to put data in long format. Then for each `Experiment_ID` you can `sum` the values weighted by the number extracted by the column name, and divide by the number of values that are greater than zero.

```
library(tidyverse)

filtered.data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Experiment_ID, 
               names_pattern = "t_20_n_(\\d+)", 
               names_transform = list(name = as.integer)) %>%
  group_by(Experiment_ID) %>%
  summarise(t_20_mean = sum(name * value) / sum(value > 0))
```

**Output**

```
   Experiment_ID      t_20_mean
   <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 K8012921_social_03      1   
 2 K8020521_social_01      2   
 3 K8020521_social_02      2.5 
 4 K8020521_social_03      3.5 
 5 K8020521_social_04      2.33
 6 K8020521_social_05      2.67
 7 K8021221_social_01      3.5 
 8 K8021221_social_03      2   
 9 K8021221_social_04      3.5 
10 SG100520_social_01      2.5
```